# How can I change the image in "Wait" dialog using Symbian

Tags: symbian

I tried to change the image (icon) of the wait dialog from the "Gear" icon to a different one but i failed though I follow a lot of articles and examples in books:

```
RESOURCE DIALOG r_progressdlg_container_wait_dialog1
{
flags = EAknWaitNoteFlags;
buttons = R_AVKON_SOFTKEYS_CANCEL;
items =
    {
    DLG_LINE
        {
        id = EProgressdlgContainerViewWaitDialog1;
        type = EAknCtNote;
        control = AVKON_NOTE
            {
            layout = EWaitLayout;
            singular_label = STR_progressdlgContainerView_10;
            animation = R_QGN_GRAF_WAIT_BAR_ANIM;
            };
        },
    DLG_LINE 
        {
        id = EProgressdlgContainerViewWaitDialog1;
        type=EEikCtImage;
        control = IMAGE
           {
              horiz_align=EEikLabelAlignHRight;
              vert_align=EEikLabelAlignVTop;
              bmpfile = "\\resource\\apps\\progressdlg.mbm"; 
              bmpid = EMbmProgressdlgList_icon;
              bmpmask = EMbmProgressdlgList_icon_mask;
              extension=0;
           };
        }

    };
}
```

here is my updated code based on your supported information but,
**The dialog still shows the default icon "Gear", So what is wrong in code ?**

**I'm using Carbide.C++ 2.7, S60 5th Ed SDK, Testing on Nokia E7 (Symbian^3)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the image a bit like this:

```
//   CONSTANTS
#define AVKON_BMPFILE_NAME "\\resource\\apps\\avkon2.mbm"

...

RESOURCE DIALOG r_my_progress_note
    {
    flags = EAknProgressNoteFlags;
    buttons = r_my_softkeys_cancel;
    items =
        {
        DLG_LINE
            {
            type = EAknCtNote;
            id = EMyCtrlIdProgressNote;
            control = AVKON_NOTE
                {
                layout = EProgressLayout;
                singular_label = STRING_r_exnt_progress_singular;
                plural_label = STRING_r_exnt_progress_plural;
                imagefile = AVKON_BMPFILE_NAME;
                imageid = EMbmAvkonQgn_note_progress;
                imagemask = EMbmAvkonQgn_note_progress_mask;
                };
            }
        };
    }
```

The Note example application has lots of examples of replaced images in different dialogs. On the S60 5th edition SDK, you'll find it under:

```
C:\S60\devices\S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0\S60CppExamples\Note
```

There could also be a problem with your .mbm or indices, so try first with avkon2.mbm.

Comment: thanks for your help, I tried Note example in 5th SDK, and the modifications in both progress and wait dialogs has no effect on gear icon, on the contrary the dynamic text note applies the new values - icons - Is there a restriction in changing Symbian^3 progress/wait dialogs icon ?

Comment: There shouldn't be any Symbian^3 restriction. You can also try asking over at Nokia Developer, it's more active for Symbian questions than SO: http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/forumdisplay.php?6-Symbian-C

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like the code you have posted applies to the progress bar animation, rather than the icon. I would guess you need something like

```
DLG_LINE {
   id=EDlgListBoxViewWaitDialog1;
   type=EEikCtImage;
   control = IMAGE
   {
      bmpfile = "example.mbm"; // Replace with your .mbm file
      bmpid = mbmID; // // The id of the image
   };
}
```

or just set it in code?

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it doesn't work; the wait dialog doesn't even appear when I add your code !! , could you please support a full resource code that you tested starting from "RESOURCE DIALOG r_progressdlg_container_wait_dialog1"

Comment: I updated my code above as you suggested, and now the wait dialog appears but still shows the gear dialog, I'm using the default image and its mask that comes with Carbide.C++ and it works with listbox lists.